# How to get currency/symbol for the logged in user

Tags: apex

I'm looking for a way to query the currency for the logged in user in a multi-currency environment and haven't found any resources that lead to the same.

Can someone point me to some resource which tells how I can get the currency/currency symbol for the logged in user.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are likely looking for the `DefaultCurrencyIsoCode` field.

```
SELECT DefaultCurrencyIsoCode FROM User WHERE Id = ...
```